# Prove that a number all of whose digits are either $6$ or $0$ cannot be a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Let $m$ be a number all of whose digits are either $6$ or $0$. Prove that '$m$' cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: Note: $0^2 = 0$

Answer (score 9):

**Hint** No perfect square can end in $06, 60, 66$. Erase the last two $0$'s and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

if you analyse the prime factorisation of a perfect square you observe that the powers raised by the primes should all be $even$.

let $n(0,6)$ be a number containing only $0$ or $6$. then $$n(0,6)=3.2.n(0,1)$$. now if $n(0,1)$ ends with a  $1$ then of course you will not find any further powers for $2$. hence not a perfect square.

if $n(0,1)$ ends with $0$ then it can be decomposed to $$n(0,1)=N(0,1).10^k$$ where $N(0,1)$ is odd  (ends with 1) and $k \in Z^+$ therefore $$ n(0,1)=N(0,1).5^k .2^k$$ or $$ n(0,6)=3.2^{k+1} .5^kN(0,1)$$ here $k$ and $k+1$ cannot be simultaneously even. also we know $N(0,1)$ can no further be divided by $2$ or $5$. this  fails  when there are no $1$ in the number . ie when $n(0,1)=0$.